# Move SPECIFIC 25k FOLDERS to another location

Tags: linux, move

I am a beginner in linux.

I am trying to move specific 25k folders from directory containing 90k folders to another location. I have the folder names and tried the following command:

```
cp -r /path/{folder1,folder2,...} /path
```

It works for 200 folders, but for a bigger number it fails because argument list is too long.

Is there any other command or to read them from a `text/csv` file?

Comment: _"I have the folder names..."_ How? Where? In a text file? Also, do you want to move or copy?

Answer (score 2):

if have `text/csv` you must read each line of file and run `cp` for copy folder,

recommend to use `xargs` or `parallel` or `rush`([source](https://github.com/shenwei356/rush)), this commands execute specific app for each line.

for example if my listdir is in `LIST_DIR.txt`  similar to this:

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
folder4
```

i must this command for copy folders to destination

```
cat LIST_DIR.txt | rush 'cp -r /path/{} /path'
```

or with `xargs`

```
cat LIST_DIR.txt | xargs -I {} cp -r /path/{} /path
```

Comment: you can use `-j N` in `rush`, for run `N` jobs in parallel

Answer (score 0):

The typical solution approach for this type of problem is to use the [`xargs` UNIX utility](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html), which repeatedly runs a command with input arguments provided in a file and/or via stdin.

Here's a [blog post with many examples](https://www.tecmint.com/xargs-command-examples/) of using `xargs`